# EditForm in a component throws exception when loading page

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a standard `EditForm` using a model:

```
<EditForm Model="@myModel" OnValidSubmit="@SubmitSuccess" OnInvalidSubmit="@SubmitFailure" Context="EditFormContext">
</EditForm>
```

The form is placed in a page and works as expected.

I moved the form to a separate file so I can use it as a component in the page, so in the page I will just have:

```
<MyEditForm></MyEditForm>
```

Nothing else was changed. With the above change I get the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: EditForm requires either a Model parameter, or an 
  EditContext parameter, please provide one of these.
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.EditForm.OnParametersSet()
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallOnParametersSetAsync()
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
```

I do set the `Model` parameter.

What am I missing? What isn't it working?

Comment: You need to pass in the model to the MyEditForm component.

Comment: The model is defined the component itself.

Answer (score 0):

> What am I missing?

[Polite] Telling us the whole story!

Here's  a MRE for the information you've actually provided in your question:

```
<EditForm Model="@myModel" OnValidSubmit="@SubmitSuccess" OnInvalidSubmit="@SubmitFailure" Context="EditFormContext">
</EditForm>
@code {
    private Model myModel = new();

    public class Model
    {
        public string? Value { get; set; }
    }

    private void SubmitSuccess() { }      

    private void SubmitFailure() { }
}
```

It compiles, so what's missing?

I've marked the question for closure, because as it stands, it's impossible to answer.